# change DOM with electron ipcRenderer

Tags: electron

I'm trying to load a website, and then changing it's DOM (and present it back..)
I got the part of taking the DOM elements, but I can't parse it back to the document.

how should I do that (the `createWindow` is living inside of the `ready` ) ?

```
function createWindow () {

  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
     width: 1900, 
     height: 600
  })

  mainWindow.webContents.executeJavaScript(
    `require('electron').ipcRenderer.send('gpu', document.body.innerHTML);`)



  ipc.on('gpu', (_,gpu)=> {

    console.log(gpu)

  })

  mainWindow.loadURL('http://google.com');

  mainWindow.on('closed', () => {
      mainWindow = null
  })
```

}